# Bambora payment gateway returning passcode authentication failure

Tags: javascript, bambora

I am using bambora's payment api service. I am currently following this [guide](https://dev.na.bambora.com/docs/guides/merchant_quickstart/calling_APIs/) for setting up the api.

I have finished step 1 which is tokenizing the card, this is the code for tokenizing the card:

```
//pay button in my website calls this method
    function getData1() {
        let cardNum = textRef.current.value
        let cvv = numberRef.current.value
        let expiryMonth = dateRef.current.value.split("/")[0]
        let expiryYear = dateRef.current.value.split("/")[1]
        let url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.na.bambora.com/scripts/tokenization/tokens"
        let data = {
            number: cardNum,
            expiry_month: expiryMonth,
            expiry_year: expiryYear,
            cvv: cvv,
        }
        //https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/
        let params = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "true"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }
        
        fetch(url, params).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
            getData2(data.token)
        })
    }
```

Here I am getting the token and calling `getData2()`. The function `getData1()` is working fine.

**getData2():**

```
function getData2(token) {
        let tokenObject = {
            name: "Aditya Dixit",
            code: token
        }
        let params = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Passcode ${constants.PAYMENT_PASSCODE}`,
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "true"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(tokenObject)
        }
        let uri = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.na.bambora.com/v1/profiles"
        fetch(uri, params).then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data))
    }
```

Whenever I run `getData2()`, I am getting this error:

> POST
> https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.na.bambora.com/v1/profiles
> 401 (Unauthorized)
>
> {code: 13, category: 3, message: 'Passcode authentication failure',
> reference: null}

I am not able to understand why am I getting `Passcode authentication failure`.

The heroku url: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com, which is placed at the starting of the actual bambora payment url, is used because to avoid CORS error.

What is the issue here?

Kindly comment if more information is needed.

Comment: Have you tried these steps with CURL? Does `constants.PAYMENT_PASSCODE` exist? Is it Base64 encoded?

Comment: I am using react js and javascript so I can't use CURL. `constants.PAYMENT_PASSCODE` does exist. When I got the passcode it said that it was already encoded

Comment: Please see the website's section called `Authorization` to understand this:
When I just used their base 64 encoder, I got a passcode(which I am currently using) and I am getting `Passcode authentication failure`, However when I tried to encode it in base 64 using a 3rd party website, I got a shorter version of the original passcode, and when I used that in my code I got the error "Authentication failed".